# Android class hierarchy and interfaces with Fragment

Tags: java, android, inheritance, interface, multiple-inheritance

I have two `Fragment` hierarchy:

`Fragment` -> `MyAbstractFragment1` -> `MyAbstractFragment2` -> ... -> `MyAbstractFragmentN` -> `MyFragment`

`Fragment` -> `ListFragment` -> `MyAbstractListFragment1` -> `MyAbstractListFragment2` -> ... -> `MyAbstractListFragmentN` -> `MyListFragment`

Both `MyAbstractFragmentN` and `MyAbstractListFragmentN` implements `IMyFragment`, so both `MyFragment` and `MyListFragment` implemets this interface too.

Is there any way to create field typed by `Fragment` which implements `IMyFragment`? So both 'MyListFragment' and 'MyFragment' would be correct type for it?

I can't create super class from both `MyFragment` and `MyListFragment` would inherit, because there are very different from the beginning. They have only `Fragment` in common, and `IMyFragment` from `MyAbstractListFragmentN` and `MyAbstractFragmentN`.

I'd like to write:

```
class SomeClass{
    private {FragmentImplementsIMyFragment} mFragment;

    ...
    mFragment = new MyFragment();
    ...
    mFragment = new MyListFragment();
}
```

I need both behaviors: from `Fragment` and from `IMyFragment`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best I achieved is adding to `IMyFragment` method:

```
Fragment getFragment();
```

and implementing it always:

```
Fragment getFragment() { return this; }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to create field typed by Fragment which implements
>   IMyFragment? So both 'MyListFragment' and 'MyFragment' would be
>   correct type for it?

Depending on what is the really your goal, you may want to either use `IMyFragment` as your type, or do some checks in code to see if your Fragment implements required interface. You can also check what is the class the of created object and act accordingly

Comment: So there is no way to tell java that this type is `Fragment` and implements `IMyFragment`? I know I can user one of them and cast instance to the other.

Comment: No, but you can tell that from the code. So you need to use `Fragment` as your type, but then check if assigned object is `instanceof` of what you want.